# In AIML, what's the XSD-valid way to use the element <set name="it">?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, aiml

In file Atomic.aiml, part of the [annotated ALICE AIML files](http://www.alicebot.org/aiml/aaa/Atomic.aiml), there are a lot of categories like this:

```
<category>
    <pattern>ANSWER MY QUESTION</pattern>
    <template>
        Please try asking 
        <set name="it">your question</set> 
        another way.
    </template>   
</category>
```

This code isn't valid according to the [AIML XSD](http://docs.aitools.org/aiml/schema/AIML.xsd); the validator says that *No character data is allowed in content model* (regarding the **your question** character data inside the set element). If I delete **your question** the error disappears, but then "it" wouldn't be defined correctly.

How do I fix the code above so it passes the validation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which Validator are you using because the following complete file validates according to Xerces?

```
<aiml xmlns="http://alicebot.org/2001/AIML-1.0.1" version="1.0.1">
  <category>
    <pattern>ANSWER MY QUESTION</pattern>
    <template>
       Please try asking
       <set name="it">your question</set>
       another way.
    </template>
  </category>
</aiml>
```

Comment: I'm using XMLCopyEditor 1.2.0.1. Thanks for your answer, I'll try another editor / validator.